# What's the best way to require source files when writing a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm converting the models folder of a rails app into a gem so more rails app can use the same domain model layer.

In the initial rails app, the loading of all model files is handled by activesupport so there no require statement everywhere. But in the gem version, it has to be done manually. I had a look at the code of popular gems such as rspec, factory_girl and state_machine and it looks like they all require all necessary source files in one file, usually named after the project.

The downside of this approach is that you need to maintain one file listing all the others and that seems a bit clumsy. And even though I have hit that problem yet, I can foresee cirular dependency issues.

Another way would be to have each source file requiring the files it needs. That would work in the standalone gem as well as in the rails app. But I haven't seen examples of gems using that technique so I'm wondering if there is a downside I'm not seeing?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're talking about model files, if so, simply adopt the same structure as a standard Rails app and make your gem inherit from `Engine`. Everything will be included painlessly.

Comment: That's true, but I'd still like to know how to do it outside of rails. Even though I'm planning on using the gem I'm creating in rails apps, I'd still like to be able to use it in straight ruby apps.